# How to set up Message in Snackbar

Tags: angular, material-design, angular7

I have a problem with Material Design Snackbar configuration. What I'm trying to achieve is to fire up Snackbar whenever there is a message about some functionality, for example: when I delete entry than message fire up and inform the user that everything was all right. It works as component and it appears as bootstrap alert, but I want it to be in snackbar.

Part of `Category` component:

```typescript
delete(category: Category): void {
  this.categories = this.categories.filter(c => c !== category);
  this.categoryService.deleteCategory(category).subscribe();
}
```

Part of `Category` service:

```typescript
      /** DELETE: delete the Category from the server */
  deleteCategory (category: Category | number): Observable<Category> {
    const CategoryId = typeof category === 'number' ? category : 
      category.id;
    const urlCategoryId = `${this.urlCategory}/${CategoryId}`;

    return this.http.delete<Category>(urlCategoryId, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`Category has been deleted`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Category>('deleteCategory'))
    );
  }


/**
   * Handle Http operation that failed.
   * Let the app continue.
   * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
   * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
   */
  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      // this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add(`${message}`);
  }
```

`Message` component:

```typescript
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {MessageService} from '../../services/message
           /message.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-messages',
      templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./messages.component.scss']
    })
    export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(public messageService: MessageService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    }
```

`Message` service:

```typescript
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

export class MessageService {
  messages: string[] = [];

  constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  clear() {
    this.messages = [];
  }

  add(message: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, 'Close', {
      duration: 5000, horizontalPosition: 'right', verticalPosition: 
      'bottom', panelClass: 'snackbar-style'});
  }
}
```

in `assets/custom.scss`

```typescript
    .snackbar-style {
      background-color: 'color of your choice' !important;
      color: 'color of your choice' !important;
    }
```

`Message` html:

```html
 <div *ngIf="messageService.messages.length" class="alert alert-info 
    alert-with-icon" data-notify="container">
    <button type="button" aria-hidden="true" class="close" 
            (click)="messageService.clear()">
        <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_simple-remove"></i>
    </button>
    <span data-notify="icon" class="now-ui-icons ui-1_bell-53"></span>
    <span data-notify="message">{{ messageService.messages }}</span>
</div>
```

Complete solution.

Thanks everyone (especially JB Nizet) for help!

Comment: Replace the body of your add(message: string) method by snackBar.open(message)?

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. Have you read the documentation and examples at https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview?

Comment: Post all the relevant code, properly formatted as code, in your question. Not as a comment.

Comment: Why are you trying to add messages to an array? If you’re going to use material snack bar, use it according to their docs. You’re making this too hard on yourself.

Comment: Replace `snackBar` by `this.snackBar`. If you read the compiler error messages, it would tell it: "did you mean this.snackBar". Error messages are helpful. Read them.

Comment: You can delete your question then.

Comment: Maybe that's going to be stupid question, but why? Wouldn't that be useful for someone in future? If that would be already somewhere I wouldn't need to ask and trouble, for example You